# Trying to setup LDAP replication

Tags: linux, debian, ldap, openldap

I want to setup master - slave replication between 2 OpenLDAP servers.

Running `ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b "cn=config" -LLL -Q "olcDatabase=*" dn` produces this:

on the master:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov,olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
dn: olcOverlay={0}memberof,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
dn: olcOverlay={1}refint,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
dn: olcOverlay={2}syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
```

on the slave:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
```

On the slave I execute: `ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL  -H ldapi:/// -f rp.ldiff`

My `rp.ldiff` looks like this:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=003
  provider=ldap://192.168.2.3:389/
  bindmethod=simple
  binddn="uid=rpuser,dc=redacted,dc=co"
  credentials=redacted
  searchbase="dc=redacted,dc=co"
  scope=sub
  schemachecking=on
  type=refreshAndPersist
  retry="30 5 300 3"
  interval=00:00:05:00
```

When I added the `rpuser` I used something like this:

```
dn: uid=rpuser,dc=redacted,dc=co
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectclass: account
uid: rpuser
description: Replication  User
userPassword: redacted
```

And I get this output:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
    matched DN: cn=config
```

Same thing happens if I try to use the admin user.

How do I overcome this issue to finish setting up replication?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the issue is with you adding `uid=rpuser,dc=redacted,dc=co`. Rather your modify of `olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config` is failing. Your slave (It's consumer these days.) doesn't have `olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`, but instead has `olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config`.

---

Side notes:
 1. Get yourself some TLS. You're sending your passwords (as well as the rest of your directory) in the clear over the wire.
 2. `slapo-memberOf` and replication interact in [interesting ways](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-memberof&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release).